# Angularjs removed hashtag in url but error on routing

Tags: angularjs

I would like to ask for a help on my problem with url in an angular site.
I added this on my app.js

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
```

the problem is that when i try to put into my url like

```
wwww.websitename.com/admin
```

it will throw an server error page.. but if i will input

```
www.websitename.com/#admin
```

it will go to the page then the hashtag will be remove
i want it that it will go the page even without putting # on the url.
thank you guys ! :)

Comment: What is your server? You must configure it to always return your index.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your server is configured to return the same `index.html` file for any path specified after your domain. You also need to specify your base href for `html5mode`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

Here is a good [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag) explaining how to configure your angular app to use `html5mode`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable HTML5 mode for your Angularjs app, you will also have to configure your server so that whenever an unknown route is requested, it serves the index.html file.

For example with expressJS server,
After your routes definition, add a catchall route.

```
// Add a catchall route here
expressApp.get('*', (req, res) => res.status(200).send({
  // @TODO serve index.html here
}));
```